# How to change the site uid in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to change my site uid(mangou-uk to mg-uk) in hybris. I changed in hmc but getting 400 error when I click on homepage category links and also in some other pages. What are the steps to follow to change site uid in hybris. Can anyone help me on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Changed the site uid in hmc.
2. Changed the base store uid in hmc against the each website.
3. Changed the properties as suggested by @Alexey

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Have you also changed the below properties in your local.properties file?

```
media.mangou-uk.http=http://localhost:9001/
media.mangou-uk.https=https://localhost:9002/
website.mangou-uk.http=http://localhost:9001/
website.mangou-uk.https=https://localhost:9002/
```

If you change your site uid from `mangou-uk` to `mg-uk` then you would also need to amend these properties accordingly, e.g.:

```
media.mg-uk.http=http://localhost:9001/
media.mg-uk.https=https://localhost:9002/
website.mg-uk.http=http://localhost:9001/
website.mg-uk.https=https://localhost:9002/
```

(the URL's might be different of course depending on your environment)

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted Hybris ? Usually this is cached in your session by the DefaultUrlEncoderFacade so most likely a restart would be enough.

Or try to delete and recreate the storeFront url Encoding Attribute from the HMC if you can't restart.

Comment: Hi Benoit, I tried in both the ways ( restarted the server and recreated the storefront url encoding attribute in hmc also). Still getting the problem.

Comment: Like @Sebastian said, try to have a look at your site URL pattern, maybe with the site uid change it's not catching it anymore. Maybe post your site uid here ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also adjust the "URL Patterns" accordingly in the hmc?

It's under `WCMS` -> `Websites` in the hmc. For your website you will have to adjust the URL Patterns (in the `Configuration` section) . At least you have to do that in case you use the `?site=SITEID` parameter approach.

Comment: yes, of course you shouldn't use the `site=` for a production environment .. and even in a dev setup its probably better if you use the hostfile approach .. but the point is that the URL Patterns probably need to be adjusted