# Customizing site url using Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using Hybris 5.7 and I would like to customize my websites localhost URL.

Current URL is: https://localhost:9001/storefront

Desired URL : https://localhost:9001/

Thanks

Comment: we need a lot more information in order to help you. what are you using?

Comment: Hi @sbattoh , currently working on 5.7

Comment: Hybris 5.7 I assume?

Comment: @sbattoh yes, hybris 5.7

Comment: Have you checked this solution out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770988/how-to-change-the-site-uid-in-hybris and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918926/how-to-change-localhost-url-in-hybris-sitemap-xml

Answer (score 2):

First, find `webroot` in your `*storefront` extension's local.properties file

you will see something like

```
mystorefront.webroot=/mystorefront
storefrontContextRoot=/mystorefront
```

Remove `/mystorefront`, so it will be

```
mystorefront.webroot=
storefrontContextRoot=
```

---

Now, you have to correct website & media URLs similarly by removing `/mystorefront`. Search for the `website` & `media` in same project.properties. Please note, below `mysite` is the `uid` of `CMSSite` so it will be different in your case. you will see something like

```
website.mysite.http=http://localhost:9001/mystorefront
website.mysite.https=https://localhost:9001/mystorefront

media.mysite.http=http://localhost:9001/mystorefront
media.mysite.https=https://localhost:9001/mystorefront
```

Change this to

```
website.mysite.http=http://localhost:9001
website.mysite.https=https://localhost:9001

media.mysite.http=http://localhost:9001
media.mysite.https=https://localhost:9001
```

Make sure, you haven't declared the same properties in local.properties file, otherwise it's better to make changes to local.properties file.

Once you done with the changes, do `ant clean all` and start your server.